# Problema com código php para enviar mensagens simultâneas para o banco de dados!

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

Estou tentando criar um código capas de enviar mensagens entre os usuários de um sistema em php, o problema e que consigo enviar  a mensagem de um usuário para outro porem gostaria que fosse possível enviar para todos os usuários, ou então para mais de um , a mesma mensagem sem ter de reescrevera.

Criei um campo checkbox porem não estou conseguindo tratar este campo, com o php

Estou usando o codeigniter, pelo que entendi ele vai me dar post um boolean, true ou false

parece fácil, bastaria verificar com if se e false or true e cadastrar.

mas e depois como crio um loop, para percorrer os usuários, estou meio perdido nessa questão, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda ai?

ESTE É O CHECKBOX

```
<?php
    echo form_label("Enviar a todos os usuarios", "newsletter");
                    $data = array(
                        'name' => 'envia_todos',
                        'id'   => 'envia_todos',
                        'value' => 'accept',
                        'checked' => FALSE,
                        'style' => 'margin:10px',
                        );
                    echo form_checkbox($data);
                ?>
```

AQUI O CODIGO QUE TENTA CRIAR O LOOP E ENVIAR AO BANCO

```
$this->load->model("Buscas_model");
        $retorno =array(
            "usuarios" => $this->Buscas_model->enconta_todos_usuarios(),
            ); 
        foreach($retorno['usuarios'] as $usuario){
            $i = 0; 
            $mensagem['destinatario_id'][$i] = $usuario;
            $id_mensagem = $this->Cadastros_model->mensagem($mensagem);
            $i++;
        }
```

Antes de chegar nesta função o código verifica se o boolean e true ou false
para chamar essa função.

Answer (score 1):

Olhando rápido:

Primeiro Vi um errinho no "foreach" vc zera o `$i` toda vez q ele começa, então fica `$i=0` em tudo. tem q por antes do foreach.

Segundo não tem os códigos de envio, mas como funciona com 1 TEM q funcionar com o loop. No código que envia, tem que por, pelo menos, um `!$_POST['envia_todos']` (Se for apenas um campo checkbox com o nome envia_todos).

```
if(!$_POST['envia_todos']){
// Código que consulta no banco e cria um loop com o resultado
// dentro do loop o código de envio com o paramentro de cada usuário 
// (nome, cidade, o que tiver no banco que faça parte da mensagem) que veio da consulta.
}
```

Comment: Sim verdade não tinha visto que estava reiniciando o $i a 0 dentro do loop que viagem, e o post eu estou fazendo em outra parte do código que não postei, mas por enquanto ainda não esta funcionando, mas estou mexendo, se alguém encontrar mais algum problema!!